# Module NOT found issue seen only when run Python code in Terraform

Tags: python-3.x, terraform

Here is my Terraform code

```
resource "null_resource" "RPTD" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    working_dir = "${path.module}\\scripts"
    command = "python pr.py ${var.P_ipaddress}"
  }
    triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}
```

My folder structure is Something like this

```
PS
|
Libraries
|   |--RUCL.py
|   |--RPP.py
SoFile
|   |--Scripts 
|   |    |-pr.py
|   |--reset.tf
|-reset.tf
```

In cmd line, I am traversing into C:\PS\SoFile and running my `terraform init, plan and apply cmd`

In python code which is in the `scripts` folder, I am importing `RUCL` python file.

**pr.py**

```
from PS.Libraries.RUCL import rud
import argparse

def pr(ipaddress):
    print(ipaddress)
    obj = ruc(ipaddress)
    obj.cs()
    obj.suc('cmd')


def main():
    # Parse arguments from command line
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # Set up required arguments this script
    parser.add_argument('ip_address', type=str, help='ipaddress of the on which we need to perform tasks')

    # Parse the given arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()

    pr(args.ip_address)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

RUCL.py

```
import requests 

class ruc():
      def __init__(self,ip_address):
        self.ip_appdress=ip_address
        self.session_id=None

    def cs(self):
        <CodeToCreate cs>

    def suc(self,udw_cmd):
        <CodeTOSend suc>
```

If I run the python script separately, it will work fine without any issue.
When I am running from terraform, we are observing

```
│ Error: local-exec provisioner error
│
│   with null_resource.RPTD,
│   on reset.tf line 23, in resource "null_resource" "RPTD":
│   23:   provisioner "local-exec" {
│
│ Error running command 'python pr.py <IPaddress>': exit status 1. Output: Traceback (most recent call last):
│   File "reset.py", line 1, in <module>
│     from PS.Libraries.RUCL import rud
│ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PS'
```

Comment: How did you install `PS`? I goes its only for your own user, not system wide?

Comment: I have not installed the `PS`. I have imported the in `pr.py` as `from ps.Libraries.RUCL import rud`

Comment: What is `ps.Libraries.RUCL`? You haven't showed your code, so its difficult to speculate why it does not work.

Comment: here we go, I have added the dummy code. So it will provide you some my code structure